# JavaScript date objects UK dates

Tags: javascript, date

I have the following code

```
 datePicker.change(function(){
        dateSet = datePicker.val();
        dateMinimum = dateChange();
        dateSetD = new Date(dateSet);
        dateMinimumD = new Date(dateMinimum);
        if(dateSetD<dateMinimumD){
            datePicker.val(dateMinimum);
            alert('You can not amend down due dates');
        }       
    })
```

dateSet = "01/07/2010"
dateMinimum = "23/7/2010"

Both are UK format. When the date objects are compared dateSetD  should be less than dateMinimumD but it is not. I think it is to do with the facts I am using UK dates dd/mm/yyyy. What would I need to change to get this working?

Comment: UK dates are "dd/MM/yyyy" not "mm/dd/yyyy".

Comment: Been one of those days. Updated question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The JavaScript `Date` constructor doesn't parse strings in that form (whether in UK or U.S. format). See [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) for details, but you can construct the dates part by part:

```
new Date(year, month, day);
```

[MomentJS](http://momentjs.com) might be useful for dealing with dates flexibly. (This answer previously linked to [this lib](http://www.datejs.com/), but it's not been maintained in a long time.)

Answer (score 13):

This is how I ended up doing it:

```
 var lastRunDateString ='05/04/2012'; \\5th april 2012
 var lastRunDate = new Date(lastRunDateString.split('/')[2], lastRunDateString.split('/')[1] - 1, lastRunDateString.split('/')[0]);
```

Note the month indexing is from 0-11.

Answer (score 11):

```
var dateString ='23/06/2015';
var splitDate = dateString.split('/');
var month = splitDate[1] - 1; //Javascript months are 0-11

var date = new Date(splitDate[2], month, splitDate[0]);
```

Answer (score 5):

- Split the date into day, month, year parts using `dateSet.split('/')`
- Pass these parts in the right order to the [Date constructor.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Date)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is problem with the date format you are using. If you are not setting a date format the default date that is used is `'mm/dd/yy`. So you should set your preferred date formate when you create it as following when you create the date picker:

```
$(".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy' });
```

or you can set it later as:

```
$.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yyyy');
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try to create a date object:

```
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
```

Example:

```
dateSetD = new Date(dateSet.year, dateSet.month, dateSet.day);
```

Note: JavaScript Date object's month starts with 00, so you need to adjust your dateset accordingly.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have Python-style keyword arguments. What you're doing in the example is assigning `dateSet.year` to an accidental global variable `year`!