# How can i change date format to British in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript date objects UK dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117262/javascript-date-objects-uk-dates)

I have the following code and I am having problem setting the date format to british i.e

```
var birthday = new Date("20/9/1988");
```

when I run the code I get `You are NaN years old`. error but If i change it to say 09/20.1988 it works

```
var birthday = new Date("20/9/1988");
var today = new Date();
var years = today.getFullYear() - birthday.getFullYear();

// Reset birthday to the current year.
birthday.setFullYear(today.getFullYear());

// If the user's birthday has not occurred yet this year, subtract 1.
if (today < birthday)
{
    years--;
}
document.write("You are " + years + " years old.");

// Output: You are years years old.
```

Comment: `How can i change date format to British in JavaScript?`

Comment: Check this for reference: [Stack overflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117262/javascript-date-objects-uk-dates

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript now supports dates in [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, it is beneficial to use standardised formats wherever possible - you'll experience far fewer compatibility issues:

```
var birthday = new Date("1988-09-20");
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is the one described in question [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse):

> I would recommend you to parse your date string manually, and use the
>   Date constructor with the year, month and day arguments to avoid
>   ambiguity

You can create your own parse method for your date format like this (from question [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse)):

```
// Parse date in dd/mm/yyyy format
function parseDate(input)
{
    // Split the date, divider is '/'
    var parts = input.match(/(\d+)/g);

    // Build date (months are 0-based)
    return new Date(parts[2], parts[1]-1, parts[0]);
}
```