# New date function javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have a date string *13/05/2016 08:18*, in order to get a date from that string I use
`new Date(13/05/2016 08:18)` function but it gives an error because the function understands 13 as month not a day, what can I do to tell JavaScript that 13 is a day, not a month

Comment: Can you update your code for me?

Comment: Dealing with dates in JS can be extremely annyoing. I highly recommend using something like moment.js, it saved me a lot of time. (http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript date objects UK dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117262/javascript-date-objects-uk-dates)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what can I do to tell javascript that 13 is a day, not a month

Don't rely on JS constructor (that takes string as an argument) to parse any date format for you. You need to do it on your own

```
var dateStr = "13/05/2016 08:18";
var date = dateStr.split(/\s|\/|:/);
var d = new Date(date[2], date[1], date[0], date[3], date[4]);
```

Comment: The second parameter of Date expects a month index. By running it the way you have it returns `Mon Jun 13 2016 08:18:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)`. You need to minus `1` from `date[1]`

Answer (score 0):

The Date() objects has a few different constructors, but not all browsers support all of them. The version that is supported by (as far as I know) all major browsers, including IE8 is 'yyyy/mm/dd 00:00:00' so in order to instantiate a valid Date that would work on all browsers you'll need something like `new Date('2016/05/13 08:18:00')`.

Comment: ECMAScript specifies only a subset of ISO 8601 formats, and even they are unreliable. Far better to manually parse strings as for gurvinder372's answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are some workaround but http://momentjs.com/ is really good. Its a great helper library to handle datetime.

Then you can do things like:

```
var day = moment("12-25-1995", "MM-DD-YYYY");
```

or

```
var day = moment("25/12/1995", "DD/MM/YYYY");
```

then operate on the date

```
day.add('days', 7)
```

and to get the native javascript date

```
day.toDate();
```

Comment: Agreed, moment.js it's really good to manipulate dates. But only if you need manipulate several dates in several ways, if not, this is a big plugin to only display a date.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Its not the best way but you could try this trick:

```
var dstring = '13/05/2016 08:18';
var nstr = dstring.split('/');
var datestring = nstr[1]+"-"+nstr[0]+"-"+nstr[2];
var d = new Date(datestring);
console.log(d);
```

Comment: You're right, it's not the best way. Having split the string into it's parts, you should call the Date constructor as for gurvinder372's answer. ;-)