# Invalid date on parsing C# datetime in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datetime

I am trying to parse the c# date to javascript date, But it is returning `Invalid Date`.

Any Ideas?

```
var dt = "27/09/2016 00:00:00";
var parsedDate = new Date(Date.parse(dt))
```

Comment: Have you tried using moment.js?

Comment: The issue is because the date is in UK format, not because of C#. You need to convert it to US format - `MM/DD/YYYY`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12106445/519413) in the duplicate I marked for a solution.

Comment: i think you're also doing too much work. you don't need to parse inside the constructor, they are equivalent

Comment: Are you try use ISO format date ("27-09-2016 00:00:00")?